# How to deal with this message : IMPORTANT: please install Org from GNU ELPA as Org ELPA will close before Org 9.6

Tags: org-mode, package-repositories

This message occur when I open an org file.

I've put this in my init file :

```
  (require 'package)
   (add-to-list 'package-archives
                '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
  (add-to-list 'package-archives
               '("elpa" .  "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/" ) t)
  (add-to-list ' package-archives '("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
```

Can anyone tell me specifically what I need to do to avoid this message?

Comment: Remove the last line.

Comment: That does not make any change. I made the message disappear removing a buggy package org-plus-??? which name I don't exactly remember.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to remove all "org-plus-contrib" references in your init file and replace them by "org-contrib".

Comment: org-contrib is unknown on my installation. I don't miss it.

Comment: Did you install it with package-list-packages function ?

Comment: It doesn't change anything.

Comment: You also need to remove the old package (`M-x package-delete RET org-plus-contrib`).  If you use `use-package` you can then restart emacs and it will install the new version (if you updated your emacs.el).  Alternatively you can manually install the replacement org-contrib package.

Answer (score 16):

In my experience there are 4 step you may need to take to avoid this annoying message:

1. Remove the org package source in your emacs config.

   Just remove the line `(add-to-list ' package-archives '("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)`
2. Delete all `org-*` packages which status is `installed` in your `M-x list-package`.

   You can use `/ s installed` to filter all the installed packages in `list-package` page. Careful, don't delete the `org` package which status is `builtin`, or you need to reinstall it later.
3. Delete the package cache in elpa cache directory, the default location is `~/.emacs.d/elpa/`. Delete all files started with `org-*`.
4. If you are using native lisp compilation, delete the compiled caches, the default location is `~/.emacs.d/eln-cache/<your-emacs-version>/`.

After the 4 step, restart your emacs, the message should disappeared.

Additionally, if your install you package using `use-package` you may want to  pin the `org` package to your GNU source like follow, then `use-package` would try to download `org` package only from the GNU source.

```
(use-package org
  :pin gnu)
```

Comment: `~/.emacs.d/epla/` should be `~/.emacs.d/elpa/`.

Comment: You're a life saver, thank you!!!